# application compatibilty with black berry 8310

Tags: blackberry

when i am uploading my app on device using desktop manager ,it shows error that application is not compatible with the device ,how can i fix this bug.I am using latest JDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What OS is your 8310 device? I guess it is 4.5.

> I am using latest JDE

What API version your app uses? I guess it is OS 6. Make sure your code does not use APIs higher that the OS of the device. E.g. if your 8310 is OS 4.5 device, then make sure the code does not use APIs from OS 4.6/4.6.1/4.7/4.7.1/5.0/6.0/etc. I would recommed to install/use JDE 4.5 to build the project for such device - it will not allow you to build if any unsupported APIs are used in the code (you will also get a message where the problem is located in the code).

Comment: I am only using Hello world nothing else ,its also giving sami error on 9000

Comment: @Ali: Edit your question - post your code (if it's a Hello World it should be small enough to post) and exact error message. Also name the versions of OS on device and of the JDE you use to build. Otherwise it is just a time wasting.

Comment: I need to develop for os 4.6 and 5.0 but i have latest JDE for OS 6 ,I not able to find JDE for it ,or how can i make my code compatible for that

Comment: @Ali: check the download section here - http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javadevenv.jsp?RMID=MR00660_NA_EN_MU_20110211_DevNews_Bytes&RRID=4B61F9D5E0DC65B6E10000000A50143D There are all versions available.